# Cassandra one seed node showing out of cluster

Tags: cassandra, centos

I have a Cassandra cluster consisting of two 5 nodes with two seed nodes. I have configured it couple of days back and all nodes appeared in the cluster. Today when I checked, I see one of the seed nodes out of cluster. Following is what I see when I do a nodetool status from the seed node
[image]

When I check status from any other node, it gives the following:
[image]

I cross verified the configs and everything matches on all 5 nodes in the cluster. I tried multiple restarts and nothing resolved the issue. In the logs I found logs related to some keyspaces in my project, but we have not connected this to anything sofar and it appeared strange.

I am not worried about any data loss, I am trying to restore the seed back in the cluster. Is there any way to do that.

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this might have some troubleshooting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954630/cassandra-cluster-why-node-shows-unreachable

Comment: @IronMan, I did not find any troubleshooting that could help in the above link. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

Please check your " cassandra-topology.properties" if using PropertyFileSnitch or "cassandra.rackdc.properties if using GossipingPropertyFileSnitch. Rack and datacenter configs are read from these files depending on snitch you are using.

Comment: I use GossipingPropertyFileSnitch and the cassandra.rackdc.properties is the same for all 5 nodes. Infact the 5 was connecting as a cluster last day and then something messed up. I compared the propeties of my two seed nodes and all of them match